# Sortable.js/Vue Draggable Cursor

Tags: sortablejs, vuedraggable

Can someone tell me where this cursor is coming from on Sortable.js? I have looked through all the CSS files and JS files and can't find where this cursor comes from. I am hoping to use a `cursor: grab;` and `cursor: grabbed` style on it instead.

Also, I am using Vue Draggable in production, but I believe this is inherited from Sortable.js.

[Cursor Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF2Hv.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've just faced the same issue. and I with some googling found [this answer](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/246#issuecomment-584851359). make sure to set `forceFallback` option to `true`. here's another simplified [answer](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/815). I've applied this solution and it's actually working great.